# Net Core: 'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'IgnoreRoute'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I am migrating a project from .Net 4.6.2 to .Net Core 2.0. What is the replacement for `IgnoreRoute` in .Net Core?

I'm receiving the error below:

**Code:**

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

**Error:**

> 'RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'IgnoreRoute' and no accessible extension method 'IgnoreRoute' accepting a first argument of type 'RouteCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)Web.Core\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing

Comment: Are you migrating manually? Do you know how ASP.NET Core works? How DI works? Have you seen and worked with the default ASP.NET Core template?